# Simchas Torah Song

Tags: zohar, simchat-torah

On *Simchas Torah*, people sing  [ישראל ואורייתא וקודשא בריך הוא חד הוא](http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=290#rec).

However, the *Zohar* ([Acharei Mos, Chapter 50, Sefaria section 299](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Achrei_Mot.50.299?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&lang=he)) says differently:

...,קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא, אוֹרַיְיתָא, וְיִשְׂרָאֵל. וְכָל חַד

If that's the case, why do people sing this Zohar backward?

Comment: Please add additional info and a link, perhaps, to who sings this. Which nusach / group of people, and which Siddur have you seen this?

Comment: Is this off topic?

Comment: @Chaim I can't see any reason why it would be. What is your concern?

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that although the words for this song are attributed to the Zohar, the idea is from the Zohar, however the way the words are sung is based on the writings of Rabbi Chaim Volozhin in Nefesh HaChaim.

I will add in the exact location in Nefesh HaChaim as soon as I find it.

Comment: ...And wouldn't be logical to say that Rabbi Chaim Volozhiner pulled the words from the Zohar, himself being a kabbalist and Zoharic scholar? I think this makes the question a bit more confusing than answering it.

Comment: It would be nice to get the connection to _Nefesh haChaim_, I found it unexpected